# Should I use dependency injection on these domain classes?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Do I use dependency injection in the following example:

```
@Scope("prototype")
@Component
public class Order{
    @Autowired
    public Order(User user,List<OrderItem> items,.......){
```

Now somewhere else:

```
@Component
public class PersistOrder{
    @Autowired
    Provider<Order> orderProvider;

    public void prepareOrder() {
        Order order = orderProvider.get();
```

AS JSR-330 states, the get() method of [Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html) returns a new instance of Order, but what objects are passed to the new order's constructor? As you can see the order has its own dependencies that has to be injected before the actual order object is retrieved to the method.

Without DI I simply create all neccessary arguments and pass them to the constructor of the new order. So should I use DI here?

**EDIT:**

This is what the code would seem without DI:

```
@Component
public class PersistOrder{

    public void prepareOrder() {
        User user=userDao.get(userId);
        List<OrderItem> orderItems=orderItemDao.getAll(orderItemIds);
        Order order = new SmartPhoneOrder(user,orderItems);
```

As you see I have the ids of user and order items and can get their instances from DAOs. Then I pass these instances to the constructor of a subclass of the Order to get an instance. The process seems very clear to me. I mean how can I do this work with DI so that my code enjoy decoupling between PersistOrder and Order classes? Or using DI in this example makes the logic more complex?

Comment: I think you've conflated orders with an order service. You'd normally pass a user to a service that returns a user's orders, and you'd do so when you make the call.

Comment: Actually I have simplified the example. Yes the service's prepareOrder() has arguments that are provided from view but It doesn't change the concept. Suppose I have references to all the neccessary objects for a meaningful order (like user,items,...).Still I have to pass them to the order's constructor.That's the problem because spring takes care of instantiating the new order when I call get()

Comment: I have edited the question and removed the mention to my service. Now I think the question is less confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without dependency injection, domain objects can be considered anaemic, and this is arguably an anti-pattern. You're losing many of the benefits of OO, by having data structures, without associated behaviors. For example, to evaluate Order.isValid() you may need to inject some dependency to perform the validation.

You can get dependency injection on classes outside the context of the Spring container by using:

```
@Configurable
```

You then declare the recipe for the bean as a protoype, and Spring will use AOP to swizzle the constructor and look up the required dependencies. . Even though its looking up the dependencies, the net effect for you is dependency injection, because you'd only have to change one line to inject something else that evaluates Order.isValid().

This way when you do new Order, or get it from you persistence factory, it already has the dependencies "injected".

To do this requires aspectJ weaving and not just Proxy/CGLib weaving, which is the default. You can use either runtime weaving with a Java agent or build-time weaving. . . I recommend the former for integration tests and the latter for deployment. . .

**Service vs Domain Object:**

Now that you have the option of rich domain objects the question becomes where to put stuff. Service vs Entity? My take is that the service should orchestrate a use-case specific process based on reusable domain objects. The service is your non-OO gateway for outside subscribers into you system.

. . Google Spring @Configurable for more information and tutorials on AspectJ-based dependency injection of domain classes.

Comment: As an alternative to the Spring @Configurable you can use this project https://github.com/sabomichal/spring-injector. Disclaimer. I am the author.